# Unable to update dropdown values in Grid

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Below is the code to update gridview. In gridview, i m using dropdownlists, datepicker and text boxes in the update grid. I m getting all the value correct..
Main issue is i m not able to update **Case_Status** and **Case_Type** in the database. if i m updating then both values updated as NULL in database.
I checked the values of **V1** and **V2** by using breakpoints in Visual Studio. Both values are desired result. but updating NULL...

On " **GridView1.EditIndex = -1;**"   I am getting value **4** while checking through breakpoints..

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name = @case_name, Case_Type = @Case_Type, Case_Status = @Case_Status, assigned_date = @assigned_date, assigned_to = @assigned_to, date_withdrawn= @date_withdrawn, date_delivered= @date_delivered, qc_by = @qc_by,  qc_date= @qc_date, additional_notes = @additional_notes WHERE (case_number = @case_number)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@case_number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = case_number;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@case_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = case_name;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Type", v1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Status", v2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@assigned_date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = assigned_date;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assigned_to", assigned_to);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_withdrawn", date_withdrawn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_delivered", date_delivered);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qc_by", qc_by);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qc_date", qc_date);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@additional_notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = additional_notes;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: What's the DbType of Case_Type and Case_Status?

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Type", Integer.Parse(v1));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Status", Integer.Parse(v2));
```

Try this code!

Comment: you should use "int.Parse(V1)"

Answer (score 0):

convert your value into string.....

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Type", v1.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Status", v2.ToString());
```

Comment: both type must be same.... your datatype in database and datatype while inserting data must be same...